# Is the gray insulance material asbestos?

Tags: insulation, furnace, asbestos

This is a furnace room.

Is the gray insulation material (on the wall and above the pipes) asbestos?

[image: Asbestos Picture 1]
[image: ][1]]

Comment: seriously? .... you are asking about the insulation and you do not post a closeup picture? ........ anyway, it looks like fiberglass

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need a close-up picture of your insulation before we can say anything definitive about its composition.

Comment: From that photo you showed us a horrible vent job on the water heater! Holy cow I hope you have a carbonmonoxide monitor, I don't think I have ever seen such a mess. We do need a better photo, are you talking about the top right where the pipes enter the wall? To me that looks like cellulose but it could be kitty litter from the resolution. The rest looks like dirty fiberglass that is loaded with dust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a trick of the photo that it looks yellowish, or is it really that color?
There is a product called "Rockwool" that USED to be made from asbestos and is now made with other minerals. The asbestos version, again pre-1973, was definitely grey and when they changed to other minerals, they changed the color to that sort of yellowish tint.

Answer (score 0):

Asbestos insulation was only manufactured as: loose fill, spray on or block types. I do not know of any roll-type purely asbestos insulation. The EPA began banning some asbestos products in 1973 and continued a series of bans all the way through 1989. The EPA has allowed a panel-type asbestos to be used in some Government facilities and allows some products to contain small amounts of asbestos. Depending on the age of your home, the likelihood of that being asbestos would be slim. FHA homes require an appraisal before selling them. FHA appraisers probably would have seen the exposed asbestos because their appraisals are more strict. If asbestos was found, the home seller would have been required to remove it.

There is now an asbestos test kit available for homeowners...

[image: Asbestos home test kit]

Comment: Well, you would hope the inspector would had. I've seen many instances where an inspector looked over things that were obvious (ie. no GFCI in a bathroom where receptacle next to sink). Also, homes don't require an inspection to sell. It is recommended to protect the buyer.

Comment: You are correct. I have updated the answer to show that an appraisal it what is required. Often, an appraiser will report significant defects. Especially when dealing with the FHA.

Comment: I have purchased a house with no appraisal , no inspection. It is not required and if you have cash never has been. A proper home inspection and appraisal should report defects but there are a lot of them that don't.